# how can show UpdateProgress bar during the page loading

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"  DisplayAfter="0" DynamicLayout="true"
     AssociatedUpdatePanelID="update1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="TransparentGrayBack">
        </div>
        <div class="Sample5PageUpdate">
            <img src="../RadControls/Ajax/Skins/Default/ajax-loader4.gif" alt="" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I am using the updateprogress. And it is working fine. But now i want that the update progress show during the page load. would you suggest what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery Plugin

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

It works even if Page Postback is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure of what you're trying to achieve, but if it's anything like what I was trying to achieve, the problem was that the page was initialized (databinding and all) in the background, preventing your UpdateProgress from showing until the entire page was loaded (defeating the purpose)

Your options are bound the type of data that you're waiting to load. If you are just concerned about lists and other databound things loading, then what you could do is a delayed load. That is, do not databind any of those items on page load in the code behind. This should cause the page to display, which is the state that you need it in to ensure the UpdateProgress panel is rendered in the background. Then on document ready, go back and load your databound items asynchronously. This async call will cause your UpdateProgess panel to fire, blocking the page until the remaining data is loaded.

Comment: Can you please share some sample code how to do it? Thanks!